# How to set up 2 different worlds nodes for render

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor

I have two objects in my scene cube and plane, and I have set up 2 different worlds. is it possible to assign a world node which will influence the specific object in my scene, One world for the Cube and another world for the plane so they can be influenced by the settings I tweak.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can have 2 world backgrounds that can be accessed separately by objects, however, you can "fake" it by mixing a Glossy Shader with your main Texture, and having an Environment Texture connected to the Glossy Shader (make sure to use environment texture and not image texture). Use the *Reflection* Texture Coordinate as an input vector for your image. Use a different Environment texture (mixed with the main texture) for each object you want different. In the image below, I have a different "background" for each of the cubes, and both are different than the HDRI world environment:

[image: Reflect]

Comment: Thanks, that worked well.